# Objective C: How to add color to entire cell (with a disclosure indicator)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, background-color

I am trying to add background color to my cell but was not able to color the portion with the disclosure indicator (see screenshot below)

[image]

What can I do to color the entire cell? My implementation as follows.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFCC"];

//Clear colors for labels
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UITableViewCell subclasses UIView; you can set its background color just as you can any other view’s. Cells in a “grouped”-style table view require some more work there, but it doesn’t look like you’re using that, so:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFCC"];
```

Comment: thanks! However, it is not working as the color doesn't even appear in the cell now

Comment: Interesting. That used to work. In that case, you’ll need to create an additional UIView with the appropriate frame `(0, 0, cell.bounds.size.width, cell.bounds.size.height)` and set its `backgroundColor`, then set that view as the cell’s `backgroundView`.

Comment: But won't that cover up my disclosure indicator?

Comment: No. `backgroundView` is placed in the background of the cell, below the content view and any accessory views like the disclosure indicator.

Comment: the cell.background color =[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFCC"]  worked if I put the code in the method - (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath. It covers the area behind the disclosure as well.

Answer (score 1):

My code uses (in the cell itself) self.backgroundColor, so you should uses cell.backgroundColor instead of cell.contentView.backgroundColor. The contentView does not include the selection indicator view, which you have guessed I suppose ;)

If you only want it to change colors if selected, use selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor

Comment: @Khelder thanks! but the color is not appearing at all in my cell.

Comment: You can also set the color of the tableview itself, with tableview.backgroundColor, if it suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

#### UIImageView

UIImageView with a chevron image on the right-hand side. Preferably in the storyboard, but it can easily be managed in code by attaching it to the content view.

Answer (score 0):

color a uiview with the same bounds as the cell and add it as a subview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    UIView *colorView = [cell viewWithTag:200];
    if(!colorView){
        colorView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 44)] autorelease];
        colorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        colorView.tag = 200;
        [cell addSubview:colorView];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

then add all of your subviews to that colored view.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but the following code worked :

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This drove me nuts. I tried a number of different approaches in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I finally found the way to do it is to override the willDisplayCell method like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row % 2) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:225.0/255.0 green:225.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Being that its a `UIView` subclass, you should be able to set the background color of the accessoryView:

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

or:

```
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#FFFFCC"];
```

Comment: strangely, this has no effect and I am still seeing the white background behind my disclosure (cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)

Comment: The accessory view is for you to set. It doesn't get set when you only set the accessory type. So the expected behavior is for these assignments to have no effect (as you saw).